# What is the description of the "return" statement saying?

Tags: python, return

I am going through Learn Python the Hard Way, and am on Exercise 21 where the return statement is used. When going through the code, I understand what the return statement is doing, but I just don't get Zed Shaw's description entirely. I want to make sure I am not missing something. The exercise has this code

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    print "SUBTRACTING %d - %d" % (a, b)
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    print "MULTIPLYING %d * %d" % (a, b)
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    print "DIVIDING %d / %d" % (a, b)
    return a / b


print "Let's do some math with just functions!"

age = add(30, 5)
height = subtract(78, 4)
weight = multiply(90, 2)
iq = divide(100, 2)

print "Age: %d, Height: %d, Weight: %d, IQ: %d" % (age, height, weight, iq)


# A puzzle for the extra credit, type it in anyway.
print "Here is a puzzle."

what = add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, divide(iq, 2))))

print "That becomes: ", what, "Can you do it by hand?"
```

And Shaw describes the return statement like this:

> 1. Our function is called with two arguments: a and b.
> 2. We print out what our function is doing, in this case "ADDING."
> 3. Then we tell Python to do something kind of backward: we return the addition of a + b. You
>      might say this as, "I add a and b then return them."
> 4. Python adds the two numbers. Then when the function ends, any line that runs it will
>      be able to assign this a + b result to a variable.

On number three, when he says "do something backward" and that it returns "a and b" (when he said 'them'), it seems like he is returning the expression, or just the two variables, rather than the numerical solution of the two. I am not exactly sure what it is saying.

Comment: Huh? "The return function"? "return" is not a function.

Comment: My apologies. I fixed the error.

Comment: A return is something that passes information back to the point that called the function. So if you type `a = func()` you are saying "Set a to whatever value the function `func()` returns to me".

Comment: It's hard to know how much detail to go into here -- it's tempting to start talking about stacks and register machines.

Comment: I just do not fully understand why it says return "a and b" rather than what the solution of "a + b" is.

Comment: @user3099345 whatever he's saying, what Python does is definitely to return the **result** of the expression. *"return them"* seems to refer to the result of the addition here.

Comment: @user3099345 also his note about this being "backwards" is not necessarily helpful. Sure, that line will be processed right-to-left, which may seem unusual at first, but then again, you obviously have to evaluate the expression first before you can return its result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third step given in the book is inaccurate (words modified below are in italics):

> 3. Then we tell Python to do something kind of backward: we return *the addition of* a + b. You might say this as, "I add a and b then return *them*."

This would be better written as:

> 3. Then we tell Python to do something kind of backward: we return *the result of adding* a + b. You might say this as, "I add a and b then return *the result*."

Comment: This is what I originally thought, which is why it confused me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, it's not too complicated.

The `return` statement tells the computer to take the next value, and to **return** that to where the function was called from.

For example, suppose you have a function:

```
def foo():
    return 5
```

And then you say:

```
x = foo()
```

Then you will have `x=5`. Because `foo()` **returns** `5`. You can think about it as that in the main body of code, the `foo()` expression gets replaced with whatever `return` says.

Another example:

```
def foo(a):
    return 5+a
x = foo(3)
```

Then you have `x=8`.